# Files.copy in java can overwrite directories with files

Tags: java

The file is located in the source path.
The destination path contains the directory.
When java's Files.copy is executed, the source files are copied to the destination.
The directory is overwritten with the files.
Is the only way to prevent this is to check Files.isDirectory and Files.isRegularFile before copying?

The code is as follows.

```
OS:CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
java version 1.8.0_162

public class FilesCopyMain{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Path from = Paths.get("/tmp/a/aa");
        Path to = Paths.get("/tmp/b/bb");

        Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
   }
}

mkdir -p /tmp/a
vi /tmp/a/aa
mkdir -p /tmp/b/bb
```

Comment: `The directory is overwritten with the files` - you mean that the **file** aa, overwrites the **folder** bb? If yes, `Files.copy()` docs read as `Copy a file to a target file.` which tells you that the source **file** is copied to the target **file**. You are not copying the source file to a different directory, you are copying it to a new file

Comment: To copy the file to a new directory, use `Files.copy(from, new File(to.toFile(),from.getFileName().toString()).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer why make a detour to the legacy `File` API and back? `to.resolve(from.getFileName().toString())` does the job without such a detour. If both paths belong to the same filesystem you can even simplify it to `to.resolve(from.getFileName())`

Comment: No specific reason. I just know how to do it with legacy API instead of `Path` API